# How to return multi-count of specific values

Tags: mysql, count, sum

I have a table like this:

```
id|category
```

where category is an integer between 0 and 3. How do I count how many rows are in each category. Is it possible in a single query?

F.x. if I have these rows:

```
a|3
b|1
d|1
f|0
g|2
```

the result shoud be:

```
(1,2,1,1)
```

ie. 1 in category = 0, 2 in category = 1 etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will get you a row for each category.

```
SELECT category, COUNT(*) as catcount
    FROM YourTable
    GROUP BY category
```

To get output in the exact format you specified (1 row, 4 columns):

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN category = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS cat0count,
       SUM(CASE WHEN category = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS cat1count,
       SUM(CASE WHEN category = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS cat2count,
       SUM(CASE WHEN category = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS cat3count
    FROM YourTable
```

Comment: that's a nice one, the same way I would store user ratings along with user ips which I wouldn't want to select